# Ionic / Angular, pass JSON/Array value as HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am building a Mobile App using Ionic Framework and Angular. I have this array in my services JS *(for this demo, only one value is passed)*:

```
  // Some fake testing data
  var articles = [{
    id: 0,
    title: 'This is the title',
    intro: 'This is the intro.',
    image: 'img/ben.png',
    published: '31/10/2016',
    text: '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer urna lacus, aliquam sed ante vitae, ornare fermentum ipsum. Duis pellentesque.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer urna lacus, aliquam sed ante vitae, ornare fermentum ipsum. Duis pellentesque.</p>',
    url: 'http://www.domain.com/article'
  }];
```

And this is how my controllers JS looks like for this specific page:

```
.controller('NewsDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Articles) {
  $scope.article = Articles.get($stateParams.articleId);
})
```

The HTML template looks like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Article">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <img ng-src="{{article.image}}" style="width: 64px; height: 64px">
    <p>
      {{article.text}}
    </p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Now, in the App, `{{article.text}}` is passed as it is, not as HTML. You can have a look at the image below:

[image]

**How can I fix this?** *(Sorry if it's a noob question, I am just getting started with Angular)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can use

```
$scope.text= $sce.trustAsHtml(articles.text);
<p ng-bind-html="text"></p>
```

or write a directive like this,

```
(function() {
    'use strict'; 
    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('dynamic', dynamic);

    dynamic.$inject = ['$compile'];

    function dynamic($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
                    ele.html(html);
                    $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                });
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-BindHtml instead of ng-model. Content of ng-model is sanitized.

Please see examples on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Alternatively you can use $sce.trustAsHtml():

```
$scope.html = '<p>html content</p>';
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
```

For more see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: My controller for this specific page looks like this:

.controller('NewsDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Articles) {
  $scope.article = Articles.get($stateParams.articleId);
})

What should I alter?

Comment: .controller('NewsDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,$sce, Articles) {
  $scope.article = Articles.get($stateParams.articleId);
   $scope.htmlText = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.article.text);
})

Comment: <ion-view view-title="Article">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <img ng-src="{{article.image}}" style="width: 64px; height: 64px">
      <p ng-bind-html="htmlText">      
    </p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) the input and then bind using `ng-bind-html`.

Example is provided in the link above. `$sanitize` will give html without unsafe tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $sce service for this .. refer this

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

```
$scope.text= $sce.trustAsHtml(articles.text);
```

And in your controller use it like this, Make sure you have injected $sce in your controller before using it

```
<p ng-bind-html="text"></p>
```

Thanks